# HTML5 input date default value behavior on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date, mobile

I've got a pair of HTML5 date inputs initially empty. When one of them is set and I proceed to set the other I want the date of the first one to be suggested in the date picker (on mobile browser the current date is usually suggested by default).
I have managed to achieve this behavior using the `defaultValue` property ([reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_date_defaultvalue.asp)), it can be checked in this working example: https://jsfiddle.net/6j8xwzeu/.

This solution apparently works, once a date is set its date is effectively suggested. However, if I delete one of the dates and I proceed to edit the other, the first date is not suggested this time.

Any ideas on how I can achieve the behavior even if I modify the dates multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Ternary operator`
https://jsfiddle.net/moongod101/b45uby2d/

Comment: I don't see how this answer is related with my question.

Comment: You said you want a default value right?maybe i get the wrong message you are try to say,sorry~